# Spring Instance Factory not working

Tags: spring

I started learning spring recently and doing a simple demo of Instance factory but getting error.
Java Bean:

```
  package beans;

public class Apache implements Bike 
{

    @Override
    public void getSpeed() 
    {
        System.out.println("160 KMPH");
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
    package beans;

public interface Bike 
{
    public void getSpeed();
}
```

Factory:

```
package beans;

public class BikeFactory 
{
    public String bikename;

    public void setBikename(String bikename) {
        this.bikename = bikename;
    }

    public Bike getInstance() throws Exception
    {
        Bike bike = (Bike) Class.forName("bikename").newInstance();
        return bike;
    }
}
```

Spring config

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="bf" class="beans.BikeFactory">
    <property name="bikename" value="beans.Apache"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="a" factory-bean="bf" factory-method="getInstance"></bean>
</beans>
```

When I run the code by getting Bike Object from context, I get below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a' defined in class path resource [resources/spring-config.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [beans.Bike]: Factory method 'getInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bikename
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at utils.Tester.main(Tester.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [beans.Bike]: Factory method 'getInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bikename
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bikename
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Am I missing something here? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your factory method is incorrect. I guess you want to create instance by class name which you autowire by spring, so you don't need double quotes here:

```
public Bike getInstance() throws Exception {
    Bike bike = (Bike) Class.forName(bikename).newInstance();
    return bike;
}
```

Try to change "bikename" to bikename